# Comparison between SO(n) and Spin(n) representation theory

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, spin-geometry

We know that $Spin(n)/\mathbb{Z}_2=SO(n)$. The  $SO(n)$ and $Spin(n)$ have the same Lie algebra. When it comes to the representation of $SO(n)$ and $Spin(n)$, does it make any difference?

1. $Spin(2n)$ has a $2^n$-dimensional **reducible** spinor representation, and a $2^{n-1}$-dimensional **irreducible** spinor representation. Does $SO(2n)$ have the same? How about other representations?
2. $Spin(2n+1)$ has a $2^n$-dimensional **irreducible** spinor representation (correct me if I was wrong). Does $SO(2n+1)$ have the same? How about other representations?
3. Since **Spin group is a double cover of SO group**, how does this global structure being reflected in the case of representation? (if their representations are the same? or differed also by a double cover? perhaps the parameters of Lie group are "doubled" in some way?) Am I correct to say that SO group has integer **spin representations**, while Spin group has both **integer and half-integer spin representations**? For example, the SO(3) group has a trivial representation, and other odd-rank dimensional matrix representation:
   $$
   1,3,5,7,\dots.
   $$
   In contrast, the Spin(3) group has a trivial representation, and other odd and even-rank dimensional matrix representation:
   $$
   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\dots.
   $$
   The **odd and even-rank** dimensional matrix representation is related to what physicists call the **integer and half-integer spin representations.**
4. Do $SO(n)$ and $Spin(n)$ both have **complex and real representations**? How about **quaternion** representation?